# Sell art prints online: copyright?

Tags: copyright, united-kingdom

Say I would like to sell hand framed art prints, for decorations, on e.g. ebay.

I have some example posters and so on, mainly modern art works from various modern art gallery's, often in the form of posters I have mocked up myself, with added text. It won't be recent works, mainly things like Picasso or David Hockney.

What is the copyright situation? Do I need to pay someone if a customer buys a print?

Comment: Picasso died 1973, his works only started to drip into Public domain in the US since 2019, but the most known ones of his late work will still be under copyright some more years - and depending on how UK law is written some or all of his works might still be under copyright till 2043 (death + 70).

Comment: So there are public domain prints I could legally do this for?

Comment: no, there might be Public domain *paintings*. The derivate print might still be under copyright.

Comment: @Trish there are public domain prints, too, but they're likely to be very fragile because of their age.

Comment: Basically can I print out a picture of a Monet and sell it framed?

Comment: If you download a picture of a painting, the photograph itself may still be subject to copyright (to the person who took it at the gallery) even if the original painting is not. There are still plenty of public domain photographs of paintings around though, butbut it is your responsibility to check the license. Wikimedia has plenty of high-resolution Monet JPEGs with public domain licenses for example.

Comment: That’s my question: the answer is then to go on Wikipedia, print it out, and frame it. Then, sell the result as decoration.

Answer (score 5):

You need permission from the copyright holder(s) to **make the prints** at all unless it falls under some fair use doctrine or is a work in Public Domain. *If* permission is granted, it would presumably involve you paying money on some negotiated basis.

An artist might flatly refuse to give permission to your plan to use their art as a component of your art.

Comment: What about selling a national gallery poster, second hand, to someone on eBay? Like if I moved house, and sold some old framed things off the walls of my sitting room.

Comment: See e.g. https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/153844188014

Comment: Assuming it was produced with the copyright owner's OK, it is fine. The the doctrine of "first sale" says that once copied legitimately the rights of the copyright holder to further control that copy are gone. You can do whatever you like with that physical thing including printing your own commentary on it and selling it.

Comment: What if someone says they had the right to print, donated to me in a jumble sale, then I sell it on eBay? Who is breaking the law?

Comment: I'm not sure you will find the loop hole you desire.

Comment: Basically, are you saying the law is about printing, not selling? So the printing is illegal, but selling is different, and could be legal given some basic loop hole?

Comment: Copyright is about controlling the ability of others to copy. My mention of loophole was not to suggest there was one, other than "fair use".

Comment: So once the "copying" is done, it is legal to sell. I see.

Comment: @apkg no. Let's saddle the horse the other way: You buy a poster from a license holder. That's the *first sale*. Now you can do anything you want with your poster, for example frame it and resell it.

Comment: @Trish I don't think that was what OP meant. See his third comment. I believe he is trying to clarify what happens if someone sells him a print on the understanding that they were a license holder. He then re-sells the print and afterwards it transpires there was no license. Is OP liable for the sale.

Comment: @JBentley - that was one of his questions. I chose to ignore that question becasue I do not know the answer and it seemed like the OP might be trying to scheme a way around the law. "My friend told me he didn't print these illegally, so I am I ok?"

Comment: @GeorgeWhite My comment was in response to Trish, who seemed to have attempted the question but possibly without realising what was meant

Comment: @JBentley The OP asked several questions through the course of the comments.